# Creating a method for a class with multiple inheritance (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods, properties, multiple-inheritance

## Defining methods for a class with multiple inheritance in Python

I am struggling to understand how I could define methods in a class with multiple inheritance.  All the code runs well, until I define instances - the very last line.  Please help.  I am new to OOP in Python.

## Defining Class A with attributes x and y

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

## Defining Class B with attribute z

```
 class B(object):
        def __init__(self, z):
            self.z = z
```

## Defining Class AB, which inherits from A and B, and has a method Calculator that uses an attribute w

```
class AB(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AB,self).__init__(A,B)

    def Calculator(self,w):
        self.calc = (A.x+A.y)*B.z + w
        return self.calc
```

## Creating Instances

```
A1 = A(2,3)
B1 = B(4)
AB1 = AB()
AB1.Calculator(10)
```

## Error displayed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-99458d340dd4>", line 4, in <module>
    AB1.Calculator(10)
  File "<ipython-input-13-63a8168fc82d>", line 10, in Calculator
    self.calc = (A.x+A.y)*B.z + w
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'x'
```

Also, I don't understand why the attribute y is associated with the class B, when it is defined as an attribute for class A. Please see [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv8Dz.jpg)

Comment: You set `AB1 = AB()` but you never pass in the two parameters that `AB` wants. Try something like `AB1 = AB(A1, B1)`, where you are passing the A and B that you created into AB1